# Adding some custom order status in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

I'm new to Magento. We need some custom order shipment flow where we need to track order status with some parameters.

So flow is like this:

Order status : *new > processing > ready to deliver > delivered*

In case of "cash on delivery" (COD) we need another state "pending payment"

So order status will be : new > processing > ready to deliver > pending payment > delivered

How we can map this status to already existing status? Or do we need some custom coding to implement this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For achieve thing you need to understand magento Default order Flow:**

*Please check the below image for understand magento order flow*

[image]

---

***As per as my thought***,You need to do *coding for achieve this thing* also *`need to create Some Order status basic of some Order state`*.For create those You need to go ***admin>System>Order statuses***.

[image]

***Order status : new > processing > ready to deliver > delivered***

or

***For cod: new > processing > ready to deliver > pending payment > delivered***

**New:** Make very payment method New Order Status=Pending[]

**Processing:** As per as,magento if you create invoice or Shipment of new order then order status goin to process and state goes to processing.

**Ready to deliver or pending payment :** you need to  *create new status for state:Processing.* and manage this status status depend on payment method,you must need customization.
Prevent to stop order status order complete whenever order is already invoice or ship.

**Delivered:** For manage "delivered",you need to Make new *Status* **delivered** to *state* **complete**.And make *Status* **delivered** as default for *state* **complete**

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand the difference between *order state* and *order status*.

*order state* is an internal Magento representation. Different states means differnt operations you can do on your order.

*order status* is your representation. In other word is the label you want to show.

One *order state* has one default *order status* and one *order status* is always linked to an *order state*.

In your scenario I would suggest to have *processing* and *ready to deliver* as two different statuses of state *processing*.

Hope it helps.